# How do you check if files have been modified, in a certain intervall?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm trying to automate some server functions for work and need your help. The problem is i'm very new to Python and i'm restricted to Python 2.7.12 and can't download external modules like Watchdog. I'm currently working on Windows and my programm looks like this:

```
import os, time

os.chdir("C:/Users/DummyPath")
path_to_watch = "C:/Users/DummyPath"

for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch):
    before = os.stat(f).st_mtime

while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch):
        after = os.stat(f).st_mtime
        if after != before and f.endswith(".doc"):
            print(time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S // Updated: " + f))
        before = after
```

I expect the code to compare the two values in f before and after 3 seconds but the output is always different than expected. What should i do ?

Comment: Perhaps you can give us the current results and what is actually expected instead?

Comment: You store only one `before` time, but iterate over a directory containing potentially multiple files. Since every file has a different mtime, it always detects a change because it compares the ones of different files.

Comment: Also: it seams you only initiate before once and then never again, what happens if someone adds a file? or is that not possible?

Comment: Correct @shevron. Then he needs to maintain a list (in general term)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the update times for all the files seperately, ideally in a dictionary. Try something like:

```
import os, time

os.chdir("C:/Users/DummyPath")
path_to_watch = "C:/Users/DummyPath"
time_log = {}

for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch):
    time_log[f] = os.stat(f).st_mtime

while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch):
        if f in time_log.keys():
            after = os.stat(f).st_mtime
            if after != time_log[f] and f.endswith(".doc"):
                print(time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S // Updated: " + f))
                time_log[f] = after
        else:
            print("New file: "+f)
            time_log[f] = os.stat(f).st_mtime
```

Comment: This is based on your code and works in a similar way. @shevron 's approach is better, as in "more efficient" if you don't need the modification times.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into too much checking, it seems to me that `before` is overwritten for each file and will always contain only the `mtime` value for the last file in `os.listdir()`.

But really, why do you need `before` at all? If your goal is to see if a file has changed in the last 3 seconds, just check for that:

```
import time 

check_interval = 3
while True:
    now = time.time()
    for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch):
        last_mod = os.stat(f).st_mtime
        if now - last_mod < check_interval:  # file changed in last N seconds
            print "File {} changed {} sec. ago".format(f, now - last_mod)
    time.sleep(check_interval)
```

(I did not test this code, but conceptually this should work).

Also, since you mentioned you're on Windows, take note of the following caveat on `stat` from https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat:

> **Note** The exact meaning and resolution of the st_atime, st_mtime, and
>   st_ctime attributes depend on the operating system and the file
>   system. For example, on Windows systems using the FAT or FAT32 file
>   systems, st_mtime has 2-second resolution, and st_atime has only 1-day
>   resolution. See your operating system documentation for details.

Comment: this method is probably better but @Chris remark is good: what is the user needs to do something if a file is added. So perhaps maintaining a list becomes necessary.